# Can you stop your phone vibrating when changing to vibrate mode (without disabling vibrate altogether)?

Tags: stock-android, llama

Samsung S4 running Android 4.4.2

I use the Llama app to manage my profiles depending on where I am (work, home, cinema, etc.).

This works well until Llama doesn't know where I am and can change between my profiles depending on where it thinks I am.

This is very annoying when every time Llama changes to a profile set to use vibrate mode, my phone (the OS not Llama) vibrates to say it is in that mode.

My question is therefore can you stop your phone vibrating when changing to vibrate mode (without disabling vibrate altogether)?

I know you can go to Settings > My Device > Sound > Vibration Intensity to turn off vibrate altogether but I only what to disable it when vibrate mode is being enabled if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using an Android app called [VibraFix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cynyx.vibrafix&hl=it), but this app requires root.